# Appending dictionary to a list in Python 3.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask-sqlalchemy

**PROBLEM**

I have a list that I got from pulling data from a MySQL database. Using SQLAlchemy

```
selectAA1 = conn.execute('
            SELECT YIELD_EXPECTED_QTY as x, YIELD_ACTUAL_QTY as y 
            FROM obj2mart')
```

**WHAT I'VE GOT SO FAR**

```
keys = ["x", "y"]

values = []
for row in selectAA1:
    values.append(row[0])
    values.append(row[1])
print (values)
```

The result of this code is:

`[3, 198, 3, 198, 3, 198, 3, 198, 3, 198, ...]`

What I want is to have a list of dictionaries that maps these keys to each of the list, namely `'x'` and `'y'`

The result should be a list of dictionaries:

`[{ x: 3, y: 198 }, { x: 3, y: 198}, { x: 3, y: 198} , ...]`

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print (dictionary)
```

However, this code returns only one:

`{ 'x': 3, 'y': 198 }`

I am a newbie in python. Can someone help me?

NOTE: I am using Python 3.7

Comment: `[dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in selectAA1]`

Comment: As a newbie it might be a good idea to use an officially released version of Python. Python 3.7 is Beta and will not be release before June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your query returns a list of lists based on how you're referencing rows.

This should give you what you want

```
dictionary = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in selectAA1]
```

Comment: You don't have to do this manually, you can use inbuilt method `_asdict()`

Comment: @n33rma is that a 3.7 method or is it available in older ones too?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound It is not dependent on Python version, That's from SQLAlchemy, Check my answer for the reference link.

Answer (score 1):

You can try inbuilt `_asdict` method to get the result as Dict.
Ref: [Online Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict)

Sample code:

```
for row in selectAA1:
    print(row._asdict())
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is:

#### Code:

```
def to_list_dict(data_elements):
    data = iter(data_elements)
    return [{d: next(data)} for d in data]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [3, 198, 3, 198, 3, 198, 3, 198, 3, 198]
print(to_list_dict(data))
```

#### Results:

```
[{3: 198}, {3: 198}, {3: 198}, {3: 198}, {3: 198}]
```

Comment: But, this will assign `3` as the key. What I want is to map `3,198` to x and y so as the result would be  [{ x: 3, y: 198 }]

Comment: What?  This output matches exactly what your question said the result should be.